# How do I make compiling code not bring my system to its knees?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have a MacBook with Snow Leopard and 2 GB of RAM.  When I compile C or C++ code, my system becomes all but unusable.  For instance, when I compile [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Level_Virtual_Machine) I notice that there are about 10 or 11 processes (`cc1plus`) getting launched at a time that suck up my CPU time and memory.  Is there any way to maybe make it compile less at one time?  I'll gladly wait a while longer to have my system usable while I'm compiling.

Or is this something that you just have to live with when compiling C or C++?

Comment: If you are swapping, more RAM will help... and 2 GB is not a lot for a development box.

Comment: 2 GB should be plenty. I remember when 128 MB was a whole bunch. 2 GB is fine unless you're running a half dozen Adobe apps while trying to watch a full screen flash movie.

Comment: @Josh K: I recall when 64 *kB* was a pretty good machine, but that doesn't change anything. Modern optimizing compilers use *scads* of memory to hold the internal representation of the code so that they can manipulate it every which way (some of that is waste, but by no means all of it). 2 gigs is not a lot of room for any good sized compilation. Not when you running a full service editor or ide with tens of open files, have a full service web browser up a dozen open tab, and the build launches multiple processes.

Comment: @dmckee - This isn't a development box.  It's a personal computer.  Occasionally though, I need to install some software from sources.

Comment: @Jasn: Than this is only an occasional issue, right? So use renice like `profjim` suggests when ever your feeling unduly bogged down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use less parallel build jobs. Usually something between CPUs-1 and 2*CPUs-1 is completely sufficient.

Enabling parallel building (like with `make -j`) does not limit the parallelism at all but by the dependency resolver itself. In case of make add something like `make -j3` to build with 3 build jobs in parallel.

Additionally you can deprioritize resource usage by writing `nice make -j3` - in case you use make. What build system do you use by the way?

Comment: Usually it's just random makefiles or autoconf stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Use [nice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) or [renice](http://linux.die.net/man/8/renice).